# Rails How To Update Index View Via Ajax After Dropdown Option Selected

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, drop-down-menu, filtering

I have a products model with a 'dept' attribute. the model includes a list of departments. In my view is a drop down list with all the department types. I  am trying to get the page to refresh after a department is selected from the  dropdown. I would prefer to have it updated via AJAX but at this point ill take a normal page referesh.

My Model

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :dept, :price, :title
   DEPT_TYPES = ["Baby","Beauty"]
 end
```

My controller:

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @title= "Home"
    @products = Product.order(:premium)
    @baby , @beauty = [], []
    @products.each do |product|
      @baby << product if product.dept == 'Baby'
      @beauty << product if product.dept == 'Beauty'
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js # index.js.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end 
  end
```

My View

```
<div class ="filter">
  <select>
    <option value="<%=@baby%>">baby</option>
    <option value="<%=@beauty%>">beauty</option>
  </select>
</div>

 <div id="products_list">
   <% @products.each do |product|%>
     ...
   <%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple ajax jQuery function:

```
$(".filter").change(function(){
  var value = $(this).val()
  $.ajax({
    url: <%= stores_path(:json) %>,
    type: 'GET',
    data: value,
    success: function(data){
      $("#products_list").html(data.products)
    }
  })
})
```

You have two way to do it:
The first one is to send from the server for example JSON with all products. Or you can create  ".js.erb" file in the views and handle the actions there.

Comment: where do i include the :remote => true syntax to indicate that its a ajax call?

Comment: In the code above you shouldn't add remote: true.
Once you change a select box you'll go to the change callback. And do an ajax request there.